# how can i print from service

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-service

my problem is that i don't know if the service is working, 
and whats happend in it at all..
so i want to print out to console or LogCat from the functions.

**thare is an option to do that or that cannot print from service?**

i do that because i don't sure that the service is seuccess to create..
i just copy this code from this guide to understand.

http://androidexperinz.wordpress.com/2012/02/14/communication-between-service-and-activity-part-1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the normal [`Log`-classe](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html). You'll see the logged content in the LogCat output window in Eclipse/IntelliJ

Comment: it still don't working for me, but thanks, probably because the service dont working..

Comment: thare is a way that can i chack it? maby permmision to add to Manifest?

Comment: You have to add the Service to the android Manifest... See this example: https://github.com/LukasKnuth/bike-track/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml (down at the bottom)